# Send Welcome Email to customer after contact in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, email

I'm new in Laravel and working with Laravel 6. For customer contact.
curently when i submit contact form and sending email perfectly by given email id demo@gmail.com  But, need to extend it with one following features:

1):Customer will get an email just after contact.

Does anyone have an idea ? please help me thanks.

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $contactemail           =   new ContactEmail;
        $contactemail->name     =   $request->name;
        $contactemail->email    =   $request->email;
        $contactemail->contact  =   $request->contact;
        $contactemail->subject  =   $request->subject;
        $contactemail->message  =   $request->message;
        $contactemail->save();

        Mail::to(config('wall_master_furishing.mail_to'),$contactemail->email)->send(new EnquiryEmail($contactemail));

        return back()->with('success', 'We Will Contact You Soon')
            ->with('path', $contactemail);

    }
```

**Mailable class**

```
directory
app/Mail/EnquiryEmail.php

    class EnquiryEmail extends Mailable
    {
        use Queueable, SerializesModels;
        public $enquiry;
    
        /**
         * Create a new message instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct(ContactEmail $enquiry)
        {
            $this->enquiry = $enquiry;
        }
    
        /**
         * Build the message.
         *
         * @return $this
         */
        public function build()
        {
            return $this->view('email.contactmail');
        }
```

**html view**

```
app/resources/views/emails/contactmail.blade.php

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>WallMaster enquiry Us Mail</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Name : {{$enquiry->name}}</p>
        <p>email : {{$enquiry->email}}</p>
        <p>Phone : {{ $enquiry->contact}}</p>
        <p>Subject : {{$enquiry->subject}}</p>
        <p>Message : {{ $enquiry->message}}</p>
    </body>
```

**.env**

```
MAIL_TO=demo@gmail.com

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=d6d151d01264b5
MAIL_PASSWORD=4c5c45ae453ae2
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=demo@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"**
```

Comment: this one goes to your way and you want another one to go to customer way??

Answer (score 0):

if u meant after contact is after redirected, then use laravel queue

Comment: can you please tell me how can i do that ? a/c to my code